# Probar con usuarios de prueba la app de mercadopago con woocommerce

Tags: mercadopago, woocommerce, sandbox

Integré **mercadopago** a **woocommerce** y estaba viendo que existe un modo sandbox para probar con usuarios de prueba.

El problema es que no se cómo crear dichos usuarios.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Si bien recuerdo, esto hace que los pagos no se procesen realmente, sino que se ejecuten bajo un entorno de prueba, para ello puedes usar las tarjetas de prueba:

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/test-cards/

También puedes crear usuarios de prueba si quieres usar características mas complejas como login o envío de dinero entre personas.

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/related/test-users/